# Find the formula for a function $f(x,y)$ with two given cross sections

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, functions, graphing-functions, cross-sections

[image]

I have done problems where I am given a contour map and I am asked to find a formula of a linear function but I am having trouble with this one. I found the change in $x$ over the change in $z$ but I can't figure anything out in terms of $y$. I have to give an exact answer and I have no idea how to get a slope involving $y$ besides estimating.

Am I missing something? Also sorry if I included a wrong tag or messed up the formatting, this is my first question on here.

Comment: Since all the intersections with the two planes are straight lines, the surface could be a plane. From the lines given, there are at least three points of the plane which have integer coordinates. From those three you can find a tangent vector of a plane which will suffice. Solve the equation of that plane for $z$ and you will have an answer to the exercise.

Comment: I meant to say three non-linear points.

Comment: Three non co-linear points.

Comment: I didn't even think of that. Thank you so much!